# Hints on proving that as $n$ increases, $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

As the title suggests, I want to figure out how to prove that as $n$ increases, $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases.

****Background****

I have a question that asks to prove the following for all positive integers *p* and *q*:

$p + q \leq 1 + pq$

So far, I have gotten this far:

$\frac{p+q}{pq} \leq 1 + 1$

$\frac{p}{pq} + \frac{q}{pq} \leq 2$

$\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p} \leq 2$

From here it is quite obvious logically but I don't know how to prove that $\frac {1}{p}$ and $\frac{1}{q}$ decrease as p and q grow. I generalized the overall question to $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: If $n,m>0$ then multiply both sides of $n>m$ by $\frac1{nm}$, which is positive, to get $\frac1m>\frac1n$

Comment: By the way, the RHS $1+1$ looks incorrect in the first line of your work.  This would lead you to needing additional work to validate the cases where $p=1$ or $q=1$, which is not too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n,m>0$, then multiply both sides of $n>m$ by $\frac1{nm}$, which is positive, to get $\frac1m>\frac1n$;

that shows that, as $n$ increases, $\frac1n$ decreases.

---

Another way to solve your original problem would be

to show that $(p-1)(q-1)\ge0$ for positive integers $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p, q$ are positive integers, then $p, q \geq 1.$ Thus $\frac{1}{p} \leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{q} \leq 1,$ by multiplying both sides of $p \geq 1$ by $1/p,$ and likewise with $q \geq 1.$ Adding these gives what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}^+ ~: ~f(x) = (1/x).$

Then, for all $x$ in the domain of $f,~~$ $f'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2} < 0$.

Thus, $f$ is a strictly decreasing function.

This is an *overkill* response.  Instead of showing that the sequence $(1), (1/2), (1/3), \cdots$ is strictly decreasing, I have shown that the underlying function that the sequence is based on is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n + 1  - n}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} > 0$$
So $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n . 0$.